# Try to understand call back functions in the ToDoList project

Tags: javascript, callback

So I learned that call back function is a function that is passed to another function as a parameter , and the callback function is called (or executed) inside the other function. one example is below. The "callback" is placed at the third parameter, the function passes the value of "result" to "callback" and then "callback" were called in a form of a function.

```
var merge = function(array1, array2, callback){  
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
   result[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];
  };
callback(result) 
};

var x=merge([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], function(merged) {console.log(merged)});
```

however, when I am trying to use callback in real project, such the ToDoList below. I know the callback functions are used(**I learned that call backs are used in events handlers???**), but why the format of those callbacks are so different from what I learned as example above? For example, as you can see I highlighted the parts with **   ** where I believe callbacks are used...For example, in the addTask function, "bindTaskEvents" looks like a callback for me, but why it is not passed to addTask function as a parameter? also, I don't see where the "bindTaskEvents" is called later and in what format?

```
var addTask=function(){
 var listItem=createNewTaskElement(taskInput.value) 
 incompleteTasksHolder.appendChild(listItem);
  **bindTaskEvents(listItem,taskCompleted);**
  taskInput.value="";

};
```

p.s. I know the project is not purely based on JS, it is built based on Document Object Model, it seems to complicate the concepts of JS for beginners like me who is trying to learn JS.
---------------below is complete project for your reference --------------------

```
var taskInput=document.getElementById("new-task");
var addButton=document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];  //first button
var incompleteTasksHolder=document.getElementById("incomplete-tasks");
var completedTasksHolder=document.getElementById("completed-tasks");


var createNewTaskElement=function(taskString){ //checkbox
   var listItem=document.createElement("li")
   var checkBox=document.createElement("input")
   var label=document.createElement("label")
   var editInput=document.createElement("input") 
   var editButton=document.createElement("button")
   var deleteButton=document.createElement("button")

  checkBox.type="checkbox";
  editInput.type="text";

  editButton.innerText="Edit";
  editButton.className="edit";
  deleteButton.innerText="Delete";
  deleteButton.className="delete";

  label.innerText = taskString;

  listItem.appendChild(checkBox);
  listItem.appendChild(label);
  listItem.appendChild(editInput);
  listItem.appendChild(editButton);
  listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);

return listItem;
}

var addTask=function(){
console.log("Add task..."); 
 var listItem=createNewTaskElement(taskInput.value) 
 incompleteTasksHolder.appendChild(listItem);
  **bindTaskEvents(listItem,taskCompleted);**
  taskInput.value="";

};

var editTask=function(){
console.log("edit task...");  

var listItem=this.parentNode;

var editInput=listItem.querySelector("input[type=text]");
var label=listItem.querySelector("label");
var containsClass=listItem.classList.contains("editMode");

  if(containsClass){
  label.innerText=editInput.value;
  }else{
  editInput.value=label.innerText;
  }
  listItem.classList.toggle("editMode");  

  };

var deleteTask=function(){
console.log("delete task...");


  var listItem=this.parentNode;
  var ul=listItem.parentNode;
  ul.removeChild(listItem);
}

var taskCompleted=function(){
console.log("Completed task..."); 
var listItem= this.parentNode
completedTasksHolder.appendChild(listItem);
  **bindTaskEvents(listItem, taskIncomplete);**
}

var taskIncomplete=function(){
console.log("Incompleted task...");
  var listItem= this.parentNode;
incompleteTasksHolder.appendChild(listItem);
  **bindTaskEvents(listItem, taskCompleted);**

}

var bindTaskEvents=function(taskListItem,checkBoxEventHandler){        
console.log("Bind list item events");  
    var checkBox = taskListItem.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
    var editButton = taskListItem.querySelector('button.edit');
    var deleteButton = taskListItem.querySelector('button.delete');
    editButton.onclick = editTask;
    deleteButton.onclick = deleteTask;
    checkBox.onchange = checkBoxEventHandler; 
};


var ajaxRequest=function(){
console.log("AJAX request");
}

addButton.addEventListener("click",addTask);;
addButton.addEventListener("click",ajaxRequest); 

for(var i=0;i<incompleteTasksHolder.children.length;i++){
**bindTaskEvents(incompleteTasksHolder.children[i], taskCompleted);**

}

for(var i=0;i<completedTasksHolder.children.length;i++){
**bindTaskEvents(completedTasksHolder.children[i], taskIncomplete);**

}
```

Comment: `bindTaskEvents` is just another function; it's not a callback *because* it's not passed as a parameter to the function. Any function *could* be used as a callback, but not all are and not all function calls are calls to callback functions.

Comment: So is there any call backs in this project? I learned that call back is used in events handlers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "callback" here:

```
var addTask=function(){
  var listItem=createNewTaskElement(taskInput.value) 
  incompleteTasksHolder.appendChild(listItem);
  bindTaskEvents(listItem,taskCompleted); // <-- this is not a callback
  taskInput.value="";
};
```

All that's happening here is that a function (`addTask`) is calling another function (`bindTaskEvents`).  There's nothing special about that, it's just calling a function like you would anywhere else.

In order for it to be a callback, it would have to have been supplied to the function as an argument:

```
var addTask=function(someCallback){
  var listItem=createNewTaskElement(taskInput.value) 
  incompleteTasksHolder.appendChild(listItem);
  someCallback(listItem,taskCompleted); // <-- this IS a callback
  taskInput.value="";
};
```

But that wasn't the case here.

---

Structurally, the *closest* thing to a "callback" I see in this code is here:

```
var bindTaskEvents=function(taskListItem,checkBoxEventHandler){        
  console.log("Bind list item events");  
  var checkBox = taskListItem.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
  var editButton = taskListItem.querySelector('button.edit');
  var deleteButton = taskListItem.querySelector('button.delete');
  editButton.onclick = editTask;
  deleteButton.onclick = deleteTask;
  checkBox.onchange = checkBoxEventHandler; // <-- here
};
```

It's not a "callback" per se, but it's *similar* in concept.  In this case, `bindTaskEvents` is expecting a function as an argument.  But rather than *invoking* that function (as one would a callback), it's using that function as an event handler for an element it's creating.  So that function will be called at some point later in the life of the page in order to handle that event, but not directly by the `bindTaskEvents` function.